# invoke dictionary fields dynamically by name

Tags: python

I have a function like this that allows to me to get the dictionary key like `get_key(dictionary, 'path.to.key')`

```
@staticmethod
def get_key(cont, key, default=None):
    def get_key_inner(parent, keys, default):
        if not keys:
            return default
        cur = keys.pop(0)
        if cur not in parent:
            return default
        if not keys:
            return parent[cur]
        if isinstance(parent[cur], dict):
            return get_key_inner(parent[cur], keys, default)
        return default
    return get_key_inner(cont, key.split('.'), default)
```

I want to implement some kind of object wrapper that would accept dictionary as a parameter and then would delegate the calls by name using the dictionary keys. Something like this

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, dict_source):
        self.source = dict_source

leon_dict = { 
    'name': 'Leon', 
    'job': { 
        'title': 'engineer' 
    } 
 }

leon = Wrapper(leon_dict)
assert 'engineer' == leon.job.title # the same as leon['job']['title']
```

Can I achieve that?

Comment: Yes, that's possible - did you try anything? What happened?

Comment: I was trying to override `__getattribute__` but it causes infinite recursion. Also I cannot find a way to stop when it reached the final object or another dictionary

Comment: oh! probably I should have used `__getattr__` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, dict_source):
        self.source = dict_source

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            data = self.source[key]
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                return Wrapper(data)
            return data
        except KeyError as e:
            print(e)
            raise AttributeError()


leon_dict = {
    'name': 'Leon',
    'job': {
        'title': 'engineer'
    }
}

leon = Wrapper(leon_dict)
print(leon.job.title)
```

Comment: oh! I see. It seems I should have used `getattr` instead of `getattribute`